# AI CC - How to pick and store a color from a gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient, palette

I want to extract and store the colors of a gradient one by one, not as a gradient. If a gradient has, say 3 colors, like orange, red and yellow, I want to separate them and store each one in a palette. Is it posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually....

Click a gradient Color Stop, drag from the **Color Panel** to the **Swatch Panel**

Kind of, sort of, more automated...

- Select an object with the gradient fill
- Choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork`
- Expand the Dialog Window if it isn't already expanded.
- Click the little `Color Group` icon in the upper right corner - it looks like a folder
- Click `OK`

This will add the colors used in the gradient to the Swatch Panel, in a color group.

[image]

---

I don't know why a user can't merely click the color group icon at the bottom of the Swatches Panel. It seems only logical that they should be able to. Perhaps they've implemented that in newer versions. However, in my preferred version (CS6) the Swatch Panel button won't work.